# Material UI Table increases limit row automatically when clicking back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a Material UI table and added Pagination, but the row limit increases automatically when I click the back button. I tried checking it on Material UI docs but they are also having the same issue could anyone guide me with that
I have added a link here, click on the next button till the end of the pagination 55
after that go back when reached on page 6-10 the row limit increase automatically

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-gauss-e0x198

help me out with this
Thank you

Comment: Add unique key prop to it probably getting caused because of it

Comment: May I please request the documentation URL from where you found this code sandbox link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid using duplicate keys while mapping to elements.
Because you are passing "Oreo" i.e. `row.name` as `key` for your TableRow element, the DOM creates duplicate of the same row as it is unable to identify the difference and renders a new copy of the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it appears that the row limit has increased but, it hasn't.

What you see are duplicate rows caused by duplicate identifiers in the provided Data. (Notice the *Oreo*).

Duplicate Identifiers can prevent the Grid from hiding the rows from the view when navigating.

Here is an example without the duplicates: **https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-river-3bwufj?file=/demo.tsx**